# How do I link to a "bitcoin:" URL from my WordPress.com site? Can I use a redirect?

Tags: wordpress, url, links

I'm having a slight problem, Wordpress.com doesn't play nice with `bitcoin:` URLs (it mangles them into `http://{current page url}/{wallet address}` ), so I need to do a redirect of some sort.

I found [Adding «Donate» Bitcoin button in README.MD file GitHub repository](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/48702/adding-donate-bitcoin-button-in-readme-md-file-github-repository) on bitcoin.stackexchange.com but I can't get the redirect to work for some reason.  I'm using the following code in the *index.html* file on my other web server, then used the URL to that page as the link for the donate button.

```
<script>
window.location.href = "bitcoin:17uctxtsWG3gpyAy6iJ8AVd5rdSjkJH2?label=In%20the%20treatment%20of%20Sasha's%20teeth&amount=0.0037";
history.back();
</script>
```

It seems to work (in the sense that it redirects the user back to the page where they came from) but it doesn't open a bitcoin application on for example my phone.

Comment: Also consider, you could just add a QR payment code to your donate section until you figure it out.

Comment: I already have a QR code as well.